# Get json data to the outside of codeigniter script

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1.1 . I am trying to get json data to the outside of codeigniter script.

**Codeigniter Valid.php**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Valid extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("user_model");

    }

    public function index() 
    {

    if($this->user->loggedin) {
        $json['success'] = "false"; 
    } else {
        $json['success'] = "true"; 
    }


   echo json_encode($json);

  }

}
```

**Outside of Codeigniter  Check.php**

```
$url = 'http://url.com/valid';

  $curl_handle = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt ($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  $json = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);

    $json = json_decode($json);
    echo $json['success'];
```

I am getting `$json['success'] = false` everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

1.Here `$this->user->loggedin` which is not correct.I think need to call `logged_in()` function of your `user_model`.So

```
public function index() 
    {
    $this->load->library('user');//loads user library
    if($this->user->loggedin()) {
        $json['success'] = "false"; 
    } else {
        $json['success'] = "true"; 
    }
```

2.And in `Check.php`.You must have to pass the `true` argument with `json_decode()` to convert into array.

```
$json = json_decode($json,true);//converts into array
echo $json['success'];
```

Comment: I don't have `loggedin()` function in `user_model` .  The `loggedin()` included in `libraries` .

Comment: Where you load library?

Comment: also load library using `$this->load->library('library_name');`.I have edited answer.

Comment: In `application/libraries` .

Comment: Not i still get false. when i browse `http://localhost/valid` then i get result `{"success":"true"}` and when i browse `http://localhost/test/check` which is outside of Codeigniter , i mean in sub-folder of root directory then i get `{"success":"false"}`.